# How does Python language know about the type of identifiers?

Tags: python, programming-languages

I recently faced this question..

```
How does python identifies the type of an identifier?
```

For example

```
a=5
b=6
c=a+b
```

the value of c is 11

Where as

```
x="hello"
y="world"
z=x+y
```

the value of z is "helloworld"

How does Python distinguishes these two cases?

Comment: From [data-model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) page: Every object has an identity, a type and a value.

Comment: You should also read: [Drastically Improve Your Python: Understanding Python's Execution Model](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, types are not associated with variable names, but with values. The name 'a' does not hold any type information, it's the value '1' that holds that information (namely that it's an 'int' class).

This is a contract to C and Java, where types are associated with variable names.

This is exactly the difference between the Curry-style typing system and Church-style system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus#Intrinsic_vs._extrinsic_interpretations

C and Java use Church typing (variable name has a type) while Python and JavaScript use Curry typing (value has a type).

Comment: How can it know that '1' is int or char??

Comment: becuase 1 is a number and '1' is a string - the compiler builds the correct object depending on whether the text appears in quotes or not, and of course if the characters are a valid number. You don't see the compiler in action though as it runs when you first execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) method for classes.

What really happens is that the `__add__` method of the object is called:

`a + b` is really `a.__add__(b)`

Check also [diveintopython](http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html) for special method names.

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types):

> The int type implements the numbers.Integral abstract base class.

Likewise, strings are instances of the `str` class.

Answer (score 0):

The python interpreter *does not* identify the types of *identifier*. Rather, it identifies the types of the *objects* referred to by the identifiers. The identifiers or names you declare does not *hold* the objects but rather *refer* to the objects and these objects, as pointed out by the previous answers, holds type information about themselves. These python objects are implemented as `PyObject` structure in C, which has a field `PyObject *ob_type` pointing to their types (being `PyObject` as well).

With the background above, now here is what happens when python runs your script.

1. `i = 1`: it creates an object for the numeric `1` from the `int` type.
2. A name `i` is bound to the `int` object created just now. By "bound to" I means inserting an entry into the global dictionary (you can see it by `globals()`).
3. Whatever operations you perform on `i` is forwarded to the object it refers to (being `int(1)` currently) as @valjeanval42 has explained.

Since the objects always know their types, which are the main source of information about what operations they support, python can correctly handle the `i` variable not whether it is assigned to `1` or `'1'` (being a `str`).

Static language like C++ or Java do things vastly differently than a dynamic language like python, as you would have expected. In short, they manage matter of types at compile time while python does it at run time.